# Concurrent factory/flyweight with TBB

Tags: c++, factory-pattern, tbb

I have a flyweight pattern working in serial where the factory uses `std::map` to store and provide access to the created objects. The factory returns an `iterator` that points to the object in the map. The objects in the factory are constants, so they will not be updated once inserted, unless they are erased.

I would like to make the factory concurrent using `tbb::concurrent_hash_map`, but I am unsure what the return should be. I could use an `iterator` (should it be `const_iterator`?), but the documentation says that all iterators are invalidated when something does a `find` or `insert` in the `concurrent_hash_map`. So I could use a `const_accessor` since only read-only access is needed, but then this is different from the serial implementation (`iterator` vs `accessor`).

Which one is better to use? Should consistency in types (ie. both iterators) be important? Both serial and threaded compile-time options need to be there.

Comment: I think forcing serial and parallel implementation into one concept is never good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not erase elements simultaneously with other threads accessing the map, you may use `tbb::concurrent_unordered_map` instead. This is also a hash-based associative container, but with simpler and more STL-like API. It does **not** invalidate iterators by `insert` and `find`, but as a tradeoff, it does not allow concurrent removal of elements.

If you do need to remove elements concurrently, the only choice with TBB is to use `tbb::concurrent_hash_map` with accessors.

I also suggest you to discuss your use case at [the TBB forum](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-threading-building-blocks/).